# 自分のプロジェクトのサーバー証明書のみを正としてサーバー証明書の検証を行う方法が知りたいです。

Tags: c#, unity3d, ssl

■やりたい事
　購入したサーバー証明書がサーバーとの通信時に自分のプロジェクトのサーバーから
　送られてきたものである事をチェックたいのですが、
　どのようにすれば良いかがわかりません。

■やってみた事
　手順は下記になり、下記のURLの方のページを参考にしました。
　http://qiita.com/harmegiddo/items/b72ca4f430292251c8a6

１．APIのURLを送信した時に、証明書のハッシュを取得しておきます。
２．このハッシュ値をプログラム内に定数として持ちます。
３．リクエストを投げた時に、サーバーから送られてきた証明書のハッシュと
　　定数のハッシュを比較して一致すればTrueとなります。
４．証明書が更新された場合は、ハッシュ値が異なるの定数も更新する必要があります。

SSL Policy Error:のログには**RemoteCertificateChainErrors**と表示されていました。

■定数

```
private string FingerPrint = "ハッシュ値";
```

■呼び出し元

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

■デリゲート

```
public bool ValidateServerCertificate
            (
              object sender,
              System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
              X509Chain chain,
              System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("SSL Policy Error: " + sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Cert. Hash: " + certificate.GetCertHashString());

    if (certificate.GetCertHashString() == FingerPrint)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Correct!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

■質問１
　プログラム上で自分たちのプロジェクトのサーバーから送られてきたものであることを
　どのようにチェックすれば良いでしょうか？

■質問２
　下記URLから購入したサーバー証明書と通信に使用している証明書のハッシュ値は
　一致したのですが、このページは誰でもみれるので誰でもなりすませるのではないかと
　思っています。
　ユニークである事はどのように判断しているのでしょうか？
　https://www.geotrust.co.jp/resources/repository/intermediate.html

■質問３
　**RemoteCertificateChainErrors**はサーバーとの認証に失敗しているという事だと
　思うのですが、X509Chain .ChainPolicy.ExtraStoreに
　サーバー証明書もしくは付随する中間証明書を追加すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: このコードで具体的にどのような問題があるのでしょうか。ログに`RemoteCertificateChainErrors`が出ることが問題だと考えているということですか？

Comment: そうです、サーバーからもらう証明書のみを正しいと認識してAPI通信を行いたいのですが、そのためにはどのような事をすれば良いのかがわかりません。
RemoteCertificateChainErrorsとあるので、X509Chain を作りX509Certificate2に多分なんですがサーバー証明書のBEGIN CERTIFICATEからEND CERTIFICATEを入れてChainPolicy.ExtraStoreに追加するのかなあとは思ってるのですが作法がわからないので確証がもてないです。

Comment: サーバ証明書は自己署名証明書なのですか、CAによって署名された正しく検証が通るはずの証明書なのですか、どちらなのでしょうか？
コメントではなく質問を編集して内容を整理してください

Comment: 箇条書きにしてまとめました。購入した中間CA証明書を使用しています。

Comment: 中間CA証明書について、もう少し理解を進めてみた方が良いのではないでしょうか。
中間CA証明書の購入では目的のことを達成できないと思います。

Comment: あなたが購入したのはサーバー証明書で、中間CA証明書はそれに付属してきただけですよね？中間CA証明書はサーバー証明書と併せてサーバーにインストールする必要がありますが、サーバーの識別に使うものではありません。またQiitaに書かれている情報は**追加の検証をする**方法です。`ValidateServerCertificate` の時点でエラーになっているなら、そもそもサーバーに正しく証明書がインストールできていないように思います。

Answer (score 2):

「オレオレ証明書を回避せず」という表現がちょっと良く分かりませんが、正しいか評価しないという設定はしたくないと言う意味ですよね。

http://qiita.com/harmegiddo/items/b72ca4f430292251c8a6
上記と同じことをしているわけですよね。
おっしゃる通り、のことをすれば良いと思いますので、指定されているコードに問題があるというよりは、試験環境の問題があるのではないでしょうか。
証明書が本当に正しくルートから辿れ、認証されていて、有効期限ないのものか
比較しているハッシュ値は正しいものか
確認している端末に適切なCA証明書が入っているか
などは確認済みでしょうか？

ちなみに、オレオレ証明書を正しいとして処理するのは大変で、オレオレ証明書の公開情報を書く端末に配布するとかルート証明書で署名して、ルート証明書公開情報を端末に配布する必要があります。それをするなら、最近のフリー証明書を使えば良いとなるかと思います。

Comment: ＞オレオレ証明書を回避せず
　表現がわかりづらくてすいません、自分たちが通信するサーバーの証明書のみをOKとしなければいけない思っております。
　　
＞上記と同じことをしているわけですよね。
そうです、こちらのサイトを参考にハッシュ値の一致をみる部分までは実装できました、ここからはあんまり理解していない状態で話すことをお許しください。

　引数のX509Certificateの内容が中間証明書の内容と一致している事はデバッグで確認できたのですが、中間者攻撃でこの証明書に成りすます事ができたりはしないのでしょうか？
なぜこんな事を言うかと言いますと下記サイトでいとも簡単に中間証明書の証明書内容が見れたからです。
https://www.geotrust.co.jp/resources/repository/intermediate.html

　　　＞確認している端末に適切なCA証明書が入っているかなどは確認済みでしょうか？
　
CA証明書が入っているかをプログラム上からチェックし、なければ追加するという事がしたいのですがまだ発見できていません。

Comment: なんとなく、証明書を利用してそれを実現することが適切なのかを検討した方が良いのではないでしょうかね。   
単に中間者攻撃を防御したいのであれば、前回記載したリンクをよく読んでください。サーバのハッシュをチェックしているのはそのためです。  
オレオレ証明書でかつ中間者攻撃を防ぎたいという意図でしょうか？それであれば、技術というよりは運用をきちんとできますか？という話かなと思います。

Answer (score 1):

まず、`RemoteCertificateChainErrors`を解決しましょう。CAが署名した証明書で検証に失敗すると言うことは何かが間違っています。たとえばWebサーバで中間証明書の配信の設定をしていないとか間違っているとか。[Apache + OpenSSL ジオトラスト クイックSSL プレミアム インストール手順 (新規)](https://www.geotrust.co.jp/support/ssl/install/apache_openssl_new.html)

普通はプログラム側で何かをする必要はありませんし、すべきではありません。

> ■質問１
>   プログラム上で自分たちのプロジェクトのサーバーから送られてきたものであることをどのようにチェックすれば良いでしょうか？

[Certificate pinningとかPublic key pinningとか呼ばれる手法になります](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)。

余計なことをして本来やるべき検証が漏れていたなどと言うことになるとやらない方がマシということになりますので、十分に理解した上で必要性を検討したうえで行ってください。普通はサーバ証明書の検証で十分です。

> ■質問２

中間CA証明書の正当性は上流の証明書によって検証されます。誰かが「中間証明書」なるものを配布していたとしてもそれが正当に署名されていない限り意味はありません。

Comment: ＞RemoteCertificateChainErrorsを解決しましょう。CAが署名した証明書で検証に失敗すると言うことは何かが間違っています。
　　その後、MacのUnity上での通信時ではエラーチェックの部分がRemoteCertificateChainErrorsではなくNoneで返ってきたので、Windowsだけのみでエラーが出るのではと考えており今度はiOS・Android上ではエラーになるのかをログに出して検証したいと考えています。

＞普通はプログラム側で何かをする必要はありませんし、すべきではありません。
　はい、Unityの意見交換の場でも聞いてみたのですが基本的にクライアント側が何もする必要はないと意見をいただいており、いちおうはハッシュの一致を管理してサーバー証明書の更新タイミングでハッシュを更新するという形にしました。